# cocoa: how to add a thick bar for a view?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to add a thick bar for my custom view, like Finder search as follow:

[image]

there's only tool bar in Interface Builder,I just need to add a thick bar and I can customize the button on it using IB, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "gradient view" that's part of Cocoa. You'll have to create your own NSView subclass and use NSGradient to draw the gradient yourself. Before you make the effort, though, consider searching github.com for some ready-made gradient views.

Comment: thank you so much, I know that what I want to implement is referred as gradient view, I will search it.